# Design a web service to support lots of data transmission

Tags: .net, web-services

I need to decide on a best practice implementation for the following scenario:

My company has a product for Solar Monitoring that collects data from many different sources (mostly by parsing XML files). 
Amount of data written can be 100-200MB per day.
The data base is MS SQL 2008 R2 STD edition.

On top of that, a 3rd party web application, asks us to propose an interface for them to get collected data from us and display it to the end user.
The data that we need to display to each user consists of many records (history of 5 minutes values of collected parameters). 
Some of the data that needs to be displayed is common to several users.
We expect to have about 2000 users registered to the 3rd party application, but we don't expect that amount of users to be online simulaniously.

What are the guidelines to designing a web service that supports that?
Since we know that the 3rd party application will need to pull data of several different parameters, is it better to send all of the data in one big request, or have it split to several smaller requests?
Is there any sence in asking the 3rd party application to cache common data? Is this an accepted implementation method?

Comment: Usually this is guided solely by the caching policy: *Is it acceptable for third parties to cache your data?* If it is, then by all means, let them cache away. Otherwise, disallow it in your terms, like Facebook does. Either way, it doesn'tmake ssense for them to request Amy data they don't need. I don't think speculative caching in Web services is a thing.

Comment: I don't know if they will be able to cache or not. I want to first decide what would be the best strategy. regarding "it doesn't make ssense for them to request Any data they don't need." - well they will not know if they need it or not, since it's up to the users that logs in and makes their requests. That is why I asked, which is better, to get a smaller request based on what each logged in user needs or ask them to periodically pull a lot of data so that when a user asks for something they would already have it